# How do I allow Python to choose a random line from 2 text files (that are the same line) and then store them as variables?

Tags: python, random

So, I have an issue that I have been trying to solve countless times over the past few hours which is:

I have been trying to have the program pick a certain line in a text file, and once it has done that, it needs to use the line number that it has selected to use in another file.

So let's say that the file is called "a.txt" and the other file is called "b.txt", I need the program to pick a random line (1,50) and then display the line it picked out, but then it needs to do the same with the other file, so that the same line number is picked in both files.

The code that I currently have:

```
import random

with open("a.txt") as word_file:
    words = word_file.read().split()
    randomw = random.choice(words)


with open("b.txt") as artist_file:
    words = artist_file.read().split()
    randname=random.choice(words)

print(randomw +" "+ randname)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well, the chances of collision in your code are pretty low. You need to know the _number_ of the first selected line. The _random_ number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need `random.randint`:

```
import random

with open('a.txt') as f1, open('b.txt') as f2:
    data1 = f1.readlines()
    index = random.randint(0, len(data1))

    line1 = data1[index]
    try:
        line2 = f2.readlines()[index]
    except IndexError:
        line2 = None
        print("Not enough lines, dude!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close.

```
import random


with open("a.txt") as word_file:
    words = word_file.read().split()
    random_line = random.choice(range(0, len(words))
    randomw = words[random_line]




with open("b.txt") as artist_file:
    words = artist_file.read().split()
    randname=words[random_line]

print(randomw +" "+ randname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick a random number first, and refer to that when you read your lines.

Additionally, if this is a real world problem where you won't always know the line count, you might want to get the line count of each file, sort those two numbers, and force your random line to be within the range of the shorter (by line count) file.

Answer (score 0):

Using `enumerate` to get the line **and** the line number while iterating:

```
import random

with open("a.txt") as word_file:
    number, line1 = random.choice([(number, line) for number, line in enumerate(word_file)])

with open("b.txt") as artist_file:
    line2 = artist_file.readlines()[number]
```

Answer (score 0):

Zip the two files together, then pick a tuple

```
with open("a.txt") as word_file, open("b.txt") as artist_file:
    randomw, randname = random.choice(list(zip(word_file, artist_file)))
```

It's concise, but comes at a price: `random.choice` requires the full contents to be read into memory.

If you know how many lines there are, you can simply choose a line number at random.

```
# n == number of lines
random_line = random.randint(0, n-1)
with open("a.txt") as word_file, open("b.txt") as artist_file:
    for i, pair in enumerate(zip(word_file, artist_file)):
        if i == random_line:
            break
    randomw, randname = pair
```